# Как ограничить область для клика? JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Суть скрипта в том, что квадрат перемещается туда где был совершен клик, но здесь есть два ползунка, если по ним совершить клик, то есть задействовать эти ползунки то квадрат наезжает на них, хотелось бы, чтобы квадрат оставался на месте, если совершается клик по формам, как это можно исправить?

```js
  var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator");
        var square = document.getElementById("square");
        rotator.onchange = function() {
            window.onmousemove = function() {
                square.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotator.value + "deg)";
            }
        }

        var mastab = document.getElementById("mastab");
        mastab.onchange = function() {
            window.onmousemove = function() {
                square.style.transform = "scale(" + mastab.value + "," + mastab.value + ")";
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('click', go);

        function go(event) {


            var elem = document.getElementById('square');
            elem.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
            elem.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
            document.getElementById('koordinat').innerHTML = elem.style.left + " " + elem.style.top;
        }
```

```css
 body {
            height: 800px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #rotator {
            margin: 20px;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #mastab {
            margin: 20px;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #square {

            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 100px;
            left: 0;
            transform: scale(10px, 10px)
        }
```

```html
<input id="rotator" type="range" min="-359" max="359">
    <input id="mastab" type="range" min="0.25" max="10">
    <div id="koordinat"></div>

    <div id="square"> </div>
```

Comment: два вариант: вешать обработчик не на `window`. останавливать всплытие при клике на слайдеры

Comment: @Grundy, а на что можно повесить еще обработчик?

Comment: @Mr.Flatman, создать "поле" из дива и на него повесить

Comment: Сделай область по которой можно кликать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ©Как ограничить область для клика? JS

завести переменную минимум максимум

## ©квадрат наезжает

чтобы квадрат не наезжал, нужно его понизить через css z-index

```js
let minMax = [100, 450]

var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator");
var square = document.getElementById("square");
rotator.onchange = function() {
  window.onmousemove = function() {
    square.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotator.value + "deg)";
  }
}

var mastab = document.getElementById("mastab");
mastab.onchange = function() {
  window.onmousemove = function() {
    square.style.transform = "scale(" + mastab.value + "," + mastab.value + ")";
  }
}
window.addEventListener('click', go);

function go(event) {

  let x = event.clientX
  let y = event.clientY
  let isOkX = minMax[0] < x && x < minMax[1]
  let isOkY = minMax[0] < y && y < minMax[1]
  if (!isOkX || !isOkY) return;

  var elem = document.getElementById('square');
  elem.style.left = x + 'px';
  elem.style.top = y + 'px';
  document.getElementById('koordinat').innerHTML = elem.style.left + " " + elem.style.top;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#rotator {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

#mastab {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

#square {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(10px, 10px);
}

#square {
  /*
   отрицательное значение z-index позволяет сочетать с position: fixed;
    */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<input id="rotator" type="range" min="-359" max="359">
<input id="mastab" type="range" min="0.25" max="10">
<div id="koordinat"></div>

<div id="square"> </div>
```